# Is it correct to store API network call response in a variable outside a React functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, setstate

I have to set a part of the API response into a static variable that never changes (rest of the response is kept in state because that might change based on certain actions). So should I keep this variable outside the component? Because if it is kept inside then it will be re-initialized on component re-render. API is called only once on mount.

Comment: There are better places to keep that like inside a ref, as part of the redux state if your app uses redux, or as part of the context value if there's a context provider. You can also use session storage.

Comment: @RameshReddy I am talking about a single component. Why would we need to use context or redux state for single component?
Ref is like state which does not cause re-rendering but it is still state-like variable. The response I will get need not be changed so why use state-like Ref?